# System will shutdown when running ffmpeg to convert mp4 to ogg in exec command in php

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert my videos from mp4 to ogg,flv etc, So when i convert mp4 to ogg with the constant bitrate, sample rate and the dimensions.During when the command is running takes too much time. And after some particular(10mins) the system will shutdown and am running this in my localhost with the command . Kindly suggest any solution.

Comment: Please post some code: without it, this isn't really a fully-formed question. Why is this tagged as [tag:PHP]?

Comment: I used the command                                              exec("ffmpeg -i Sample.mp4  -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:50 -acodec copy -f mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -vpre normal  output.mp4"); exec("ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -deinterlace -an -ss $clip_start_time -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg output.jpg 2>&1");                                            exec("ffmpeg2theora -i output.mp4 -o output.ogg"); chmod("output.mp4", 0777);                       chmod("output.ogg", 0777);

Comment: "The system will shutdown"  Really?  Sounds like your machine is overheating.  Clarify what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

Read about [set_time_limit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in the PHP manual. It is likely that your script is timing out.

You can disable this limit (if you are not running PHP in safe mode) via:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```